# Como eliminar aplicaciones sin interaccion de usuario en dispositivos rooteados?

Tags: android, android-studio, shell

Estoy intentando eliminar aplicaciones automáticamente desde un método en donde ejecuto un comando `shell`. El problema esta que a pesar de que el dispositivo se encuentra rooteado me manda un mensaje en el `log` de `permission denied`. Entiendo que por consola, entrando en la `shell` del dispositivo físico es posible eliminar las `app` aun así esta sean del sistema con:

> pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.package.todelete

Teniendo esto como referencia, intento realizarlo con un `Process` de esta forma:

```
private void deleteApp(){
        try{
            Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

           outputStream.writeBytes("pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.calendar");
            outputStream.flush();

            outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
            outputStream.flush();
            su.waitFor();
        }catch(IOException e){
            try {
                throw new Exception(e);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            try {
                throw new Exception(e);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Pero el problema esta en que no me deja, también, teniendo en cuenta que el dispositivo físico me muestra una pantalla que para usar esa `app` es necesario permitirle acceso `root`, a pesar de aceptarlo, de igual forma me da `permission denied` cuando intento borrar algún otro `package` alguna sugerencia?, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder **desinstalar aplicaciones sin interacción del usuario** es requisito indispensable que tu aplicación sea definida como de sistema, en este caso **la aplicación debe ser firmada con la misma clave de firma que firmó el [firmware](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware)**, de otra forma obtendrás el mensaje `"permission denied"`.

No es común que nosotros como  desarrolladores tengamos acceso a la llave con la que fue firmado el  [firmware](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware).

te recomiendo revisar:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1776095

---

Puedes como otra opción mostrar el dialogo al usuario donde pregunta si deseas desinstalar al aplicación, esto lo puedes realizar mediante:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.DELETE -d package:<your app package>
```

revisa

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949609/adb-shell-command-to-make-android-package-uninstall-dialog-appear